# How can I write a query that shows the percentage of records in my table that has name that contains len == 1?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called Candidate below.

[image]

I am trying to find the percentage of records in there that have the length of name equal to 1.

So far I tried this.. but i can't get it to give me a percentage value.

```
 select T.N/T.D  from (

 select (select count(1) from Candidate where len(rtrim(LTRIM(name))) = 1 ) as N
 , 
 count(*) as D
 from Candidate ) T
```

Also, is this the best approach?  Is there a better way of doing this?

Thank you!

Comment: FYI, `LEN` already ignores trailing spaces, so there is little point using `RTRIM`. As for `LTRIM` *should* you be excluding leading spaces? I would, personally, say that the value `' abc'` as a length of 4 characters, not 3.

Comment: Note that a recommend against using `float` like the accepted solution does; use a base 10 data type (`decimal`).

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a conditional aggregation `avg()`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Name] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('A')
,('B')
,('C')
,('D')
,('E')
,('bob')
,('bobby')
,('zac')
,('jack')
,('noname')
 
Select avg( case when len(Name)=1 then 1.0 else 0 end)
 from @YourTable
```

**Results**

```
0.500000
```